# binary to decimal using recursion,python

Tags: python, recursion, binary, decimal

Need help converting binary to decimal, using recursion.

So far I have :

(2* int(s[0])) + int(s[1])

with base cases for when s==0 and s==1.

I'm not sure how to pass this recursively so that the function will pass through all 1's and 0's in input,s.

Comment: First, `s==0` and `s==1` can't possibly be true, since `s` is obviously a sequence. You mean `len(s)==0` and `len(s)==1` maybe? Or something different?

Comment: Second, do you understand the basic concept of recursion? Can you at least write a function that handles the base cases, with a guess or just a `# help me with this part` for the remaining case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to pick off the last character of the string and convert that to a number, then multiply it by the appropriate power of 2. I've commented the code for you.

```
# we need to keep track of the current string,
# the power of two, and the total (decimal)
def placeToInt (str, pow, total):
    # if the length of the string is one,
    # we won't call the function anymore
    if (len(str) == 1):
        # return the number, 0 or 1, in the string
        # times 2 raised to the current power,
        # plus the already accumulated total
        return int(str) * (2 ** pow) + total
    else:
        # grab the last digit, a 0 or 1
        num = int(str[-1:])
        # the representation in binary is 2 raised to the given power,
        # times the number (0 or 1)
        # add this to the total
        total += (num * (2 ** pow))
        # return, since the string has more digits
        return placeToInt(str[:-1], pow + 1, total)

# test case
# appropriately returns 21
print(placeToInt("10101", 0, 0))
```

Now, let's go through it manually, so you understand why this works.

```
# n = 101 (in binary
# this can also be represented as 1*(2^2) + 0*(2^1) + 1*(2^0)
# alternatively, since there are three digits in this binary number
# 1*(2^(n-1)) + 0*(2^(n-2)) + 1*(2^(n-3))
```

So what does this mean? Well, the rightmost digit is 1 or 0 times 2 raised to the power of zero. In other words, it either adds 1 or 0 to the total. What about the second rightmost digit? It either adds 0 or 2 to the total. The next one? 0 or 4. See the pattern?

Let's write the pseudocode:

```
let n = input, in binary
total = 0
power of 2 = 0
while n has a length:
    lastDigit = last digit of n
    add (2^pow)*lastDigit to the current total
```

Since we start with a power and a total of 0, you can see why this works.

Comment: I'm trying to work through the problem like this 
let's say s=1010

`101 + 0
10 + 1
1+0 

it will then work like this:
(2*1)+0= 2
(2*2)+1=5
(5*2)+0=10

the final answer returned would be 10.

so far i've come up with this :

    if s=='0':
        return 0
    elif s=='1':
        return 1
    else:
        if (len(s))>1:
            n=(2*(int(s[0]))) + (int(s[1]))
            print(n)
            rest= (2*n) + (int(s[-1:]))
            print(rest)`

and this works for s='100' or s='111' but not anything higher

Comment: @user4127524 can you put that code on a http://pastebin.com, so it's easier for me to read?

Answer (score 0):

```
def IntegerConvert(num, base):
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        IntegerConvert.sum += pow(10, IntegerConvert.counter)*(num % base)
        IntegerConvert.counter += 1
        IntegerConvert(num/base, base)
    return IntegerConvert.sum
IntegerConvert.counter = 0
IntegerConvert.sum = 0
print IntegerConvert(10, 2)
```